# Can xlswriter 'filter_column' be set to sort a column within a filtered range

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to sort a column within a .xlsx file using Python's 'xlswriter' module?
Here is some sample code:

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

data = (
   ['Region', 'SalesRep', 'Product', 'Units'],
   ['East',   'Tom',      'Apple',    6380],
   ['West',   'Fred',     'Grape',    5619],
   ['North',  'Amy',      'Pear',     4565],
   ['South',  'Sal',      'Banana',   5323],
   ['South',  'Hector',   'Apple',    9814]
)
for row in range(len(data)):
   ws.write_row(row,0, data[row])
   
ws.filter_column(2, <?????>)
```

Comment: You cannot sort a filtered range with XlsxWriter because sorting isn’t part of the file format. It is something Excel does at runtime. You can get the same effect by sorting the data with Python before writing it to the Excel file with XlsxWriter.

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative solution

I speculate you want to apply a filter to a known column of the working workbook. This solution will add the filter but the sorting can only take place at runtime as a feature of the MS Excel.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

original_file = "data.xlsx"

# Open Excel file with openpyxl
# and loading the workbook
wb = load_workbook(original_file)
worksheet = wb.active

# Adjust range based on your data
worksheet.auto_filter.ref = "A1:A6"

# Saving the modified workbook
wb.save("data_with_filter.xlsx")
```

For your convenience:

```bash
pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: I think its worth explaining; Because applying a filter is something the Excel Application is needed for and Openpyxl does not use Excel the statement "but it is not applied automatically" means that Openpyxl sets/enables the filter but it will not be applied until the workbook is opened in Excel.